# How do I log in into Apache web server on Ubuntu from Windows?

Tags: apache, authentication, windows

I've been given a username and password for an Apache server, that runs on Ubuntu, and belongs to my professor.

I do not know how to connect to the server from my machine(windows), and run scripts (Python majorly) on it. I've tried installing XAMPP, but it *created a server* and not *connect to a server created by someone else*.

So, what should I do?

Comment: You need to ask your professor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one additional thing to connect:  the address of the server.  It can be either an IP address or a host name.

After you have the address you can log into the machine through secure shell (SSH).   SSH gives you command line access to the machine.   You could also use secure copy (SCP) to place your files on the machine.

From a Windows machine you will need SSH and SCP clients to do so. The most popular are [PuTTY and PSCP](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).